# Webpack imagemin plugin to compress jpg, png and create webp?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, image-compression, webp

I'm trying to figure out how to compress my images the best way using webpack. I'm looking for a way to compress .jpg (lossy), .png, and also create .webp files for each jpg/png file.

I tried https://github.com/itgalaxy/imagemin-webpack which seems to be working for outputting .jpg and .png files, but I cannot get to work to output .webp even if it say it should support other imagemin-packages.

My current config for this plugin is:

```
const imageMinPlugin = new ImageminPlugin({
    imageminOptions: {
        plugins: [
            ['webp', { quality: 50 }],
            ['mozjpeg', { quality: 10 }],
            ['pngquant', { quality: [0.9, 0.95]}],
        ]
    }
});
```

But it seems to completely ignore the "webp" part, no errors or anything.
Is there a better way to compress images using webpack that fullfills my requirements? Or do I need to do this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779716/9430588) though the question wasn't precisely the same.

I guess what you miss is `imageminWebp` function. You may check it out in linked repo (webpack.common.js [lines 22-26](https://github.com/Uzwername/base-react-webpack-config/blob/1ec3c5e262fd0ceb5746acdbfb3be030af7f4d25/webpack.common.js#L22)).

Comment: Okay - but that is then using a different setup than as a plugin.

Comment: @nickelman It is indeed. Yet, imagemin itself doesn't convert your files into anything. It _optimizes_ already existing images. So if you already have webp images, your setup should work. In case you want to generate them, then, well, you need something apart from imagemin. I guess you might use imagemin-webp & imagemin as plugin in the same time. I use another optimization plugin just because I preferred it.