# Webpack - How to convert jpg/png to webp via image-webpack-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webp, webpack-file-loader

I want to generate webp files from jpg/png from webpack.
To do that i using image-webpack-plugin (*https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader*)

In the plugin documentation it's written that the webp additional optimizer *"Compress JPG & PNG images into WEBP"* (https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader#usage) but after followed the documentation steps the conversion not work.

The files are exported in jpg but nothing is converted.

*I've already followed these posts but i've don't understand how to translate in a "non-react" environment :*

1. [Webpack imagemin plugin to compress jpg, png and create webp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699807/webpack-imagemin-plugin-to-compress-jpg-png-and-create-webp)
2. [Webpack (Encore): convert images to webp using image-webpack-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483962/webpack-encore-convert-images-to-webp-using-image-webpack-loader)

**`webpack.config.js`**

```
 { 
   test:/\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
   use:[ 
      { 
         loader:'file-loader',
         options:{ 
            outputPath:'images',
            name:'[name].[ext]'
         }
      },
      { 
         loader:'image-webpack-loader',
         options:{ 
            mozjpeg:{ 
               progressive:true,
               quality:65
            },
            optipng:{ enabled: false },
            pngquant:{ quality: [ 0.65, 0.90 ], speed:4 },
            gifsicle:{ interlaced: false },
            webp:{ quality: 75 }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a reliable and clean way to turn jpg / png files into webp via webpack ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, i've found a proper solution. For future people who will come here :

I no longer use image-webpack-loader but `imagemin` & `imagemin-webp`

---

## Setting up :

1. Verify you have `imagemin` & `imagemin-webp` installed before do anything.
2. Create a `webpack.config.prod.js` file to create a specific image conversion script before the webpack build script.

Into the array `['src/images/*.{jpg,png}']` is the input, *'destination'* the output. The output is via `src` to avoid to load unused stuff in the `dist` directory and it permit to a potential ejs plugin to require directly .webp files by a 'require' command.

```
const imagemin = require( "imagemin" )
const webp = require( "imagemin-webp" )

imagemin( ['src/images/*.{jpg,png}'], {
    destination: 'src/images',
    plugins: [
        webp( { quality: 60 } )
    ]
} )
```

3. Create a *"prescript"* in `package.json` dedicated to the production

```
"scripts": {
    "preprod": "node webpack.config.prod.js",
    "prod": "npm webpack"
}
```

---

## Sources :

[Pre & Post Hooks](https://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html#hooks-pre-and-post)

[Imagemin Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin)

[Imagemin Webp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webp)

Comment: Yeah till now 2020 in google official documentation mark this as the recommended method for using webp with webpack

Comment: @JuanAmador : From Aug, 25 2020 you can now also use AVIF format wich is better than WEBP ;) https://caniuse.com/avif

Comment: @JuanAmador can you give us link with this recommendation?

Comment: Using [responsive-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/responsive-loader) for images in webpack config is more comfortable for me, because it creates webp copy of image and outputs images as usual file-loader. In addition to this it can create multiple sizes for each image, which can be used for srcSet attribute or responsive background-image style prop with media queries.

Comment: It's not maintained anymore. The author recommends Squoosh. See https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/385

Comment: Throw errors on require(), should be replaced with import statement like so,

import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import webp from 'imagemin-webp';

Answer (score 2):

Try this. https://github.com/GaoYYYang/image-optimize-loader#3-transform-your-pngjpg-into-webp

When you enable compress.webp, it will transform your png/jpg into webp files, and there will be no png/jpg files generated. Your source code will directly use webp file instead of png/jpg.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|git|svg|)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: `img-optimize-loader`,
            options: {
              compress: {
                // This will transform your png/jpg into webp.
                webp: true,
                disableOnDevelopment: true
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Appreciated! But I'd be wary of using this without having a jpg/png fallback... even with high support rate of 85% as of Oct 2020 (https://caniuse.com/webp).

Comment: @GaoYYYang - your package `image-optimize-loader` is great! Related to what RockyKev pointed out, is there way to have both the .webp and .png/.jpg files? That way we can use the .png/.jpg files as a fallback if a user's browser doesn't support .webp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [responsive loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/responsive-loader). Steps for using from official doc:

1. Add to webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|webp)$/i,
        use: {
          loader: "responsive-loader",
          options: {
            // If you want to enable sharp support:
            adapter: require("responsive-loader/sharp"),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

2. Import images in your JavaScript files:

```js
import responsiveImage from 'img/myImage.jpg?sizes[]=300,sizes[]=600,sizes[]=1024,sizes[]=2048';
import responsiveImageWebp from 'img/myImage.jpg?sizes[]=300,sizes[]=600,sizes[]=1024,sizes[]=2048&format=webp';

// Outputs
// responsiveImage.srcSet => '2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-300.jpg 300w,2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-600.jpg 600w,2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-600.jpg 600w ...'
// responsiveImage.images => [{height: 150, path: '2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-300.jpg', width: 300}, {height: 300, path: '2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-600.jpg', width: 600} ...]
// responsiveImage.src => '2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-300.jpg'
// responsiveImage.toString() => '2fefae46cb857bc750fa5e5eed4a0cde-300.jpg'
...
  <picture>
    <source srcSet={responsiveImageWebp.srcSet} type='image/webp' />
    <img
      src={responsiveImage.src}
      srcSet={responsiveImage.srcSet}
      width={responsiveImage.width}
      height={responsiveImage.height}
      sizes='(min-width: 1024px) 1024px, 100vw'
      loading="lazy"
    />
  </picture>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How to create a webp image in the same path as in the working directory.

1. Create `create-webp.mjs`:

```js
import imagemin from 'imagemin';
import imageminWebp from 'imagemin-webp';

import { promises as fsPromises } from 'node:fs';
import { promisify } from 'node:util';
import path from 'node:path';
import fs from 'graceful-fs';

const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

imagemin(['./src/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png}'], {
    plugins: [
        imageminWebp({ quality: 100 }),
    ],
}).then(files => files
    .forEach(async v => {
        let source = path.parse(v.sourcePath);
        v.destinationPath = `${source.dir}/${source.name}.webp`;
        await fsPromises.mkdir(path.dirname(v.destinationPath), { recursive: true });
        await writeFile(v.destinationPath, v.data);
    })
);
```

2. Run `node ./create-webp.mjs` before run webpack.
3. Add to `webpack.config`:

```js
{
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg|webp)$/i,
    type: 'asset/resource',
    generator: {
        filename: content => {
            return content.filename.replace('src/', '');
        },
    },
},
```